# Sending an attachment with Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email

I have a simple webapp where the user can submit an attachment, along with information that is submitted. I think I have the attachment uploaded correctly, but I'm unsure of how to attach it to the email that is generated on the server (GAE) side. Here's my html form

```
<form action="http://xxx.appspot.com" enctype="multipart/form-data;charset=UTF-8" target="myiframe" method="post" id="myForm" name="myForm">Contact Name<br />
<input type="text" required="" name="cname" /><br />
Name of Institution<br />
<input type="text" required="" name="iname" /><br />
E-Mail<br />
<input type="email" required="" name="email" /><br />
Phone<br />
<input type="tel" required="" name="phone" /><br />
If you have a supporting file that will clarify your help request you can add it here (optional)<br />
<input type="file" name="upfile" MAXLENGTH=50 ALLOW="text/html/text/plain" /><br />
Description of problem/issue<br />
<textarea required="" name="desc" rows="3" cols="30">
</textarea>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<div id="result"></div>
</form>
<iframe name="myiframe" style="visibility:hidden;display:none" src="http://xxx.appspot.com" id="myiframe"></iframe>
```

And here's my server side code

```
import cgi, cgitb
from google.appengine.api import mail

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Hello, webapp2 World!')

    def post(self):

        contact=self.request.POST["cname"]
        institute=self.request.POST["iname"]
        email=self.request.POST["email"]
        phone=self.request.POST["phone"]
        desc=self.request.POST["desc"]
        filename=self.request.POST["upfile"]
        user_address = "xxx@xxx.net"

        sender_address = "xxx@gmail.com"
        subject = "Test email"

        body = "Contact Name: "+contact+"\n"+"Name of Institution: "+institute+"\n"+"E-mail: "+email+"\n"+"Phone: "+phone+"\n"+"Description: "+desc#+"\n"+"Filename: "+filename
        mail.send_mail(sender_address, user_address, subject, body)

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

The problem with using the GAE docs, is that I"m not uploading the file, I think, the way they are. I'm totally at a loss here.

EDIT: I've added

```
mail.send_mail(sender_address, user_address, subject, body, attachments=[(filename), (filename)])
```

but that only attaches the literal filename, not the contents.

Answer (score 0):

The second item in the `attachments` tuple needs to be the file contents:

```
 ... attachments=[(filename), (file_contents)]
```

See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/attachments)